# Wordpress - allow files in site root to be accessed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, document-root

I have a wordress site but I have a simple page which is not part of the wordpress project

```
http://sitetest.com/mypage.php
```

How can I make wordpress ignore this file and allow it to be shown

Comment: This obviously depends on the rewriting rules you currently use, which you do not post. If in doubt, then make an exception rule for those files.

Comment: you need to run mypage.php file, right?

Answer (score -1):

Just upload this php file to your `/public_html` directory and run as usually `http://sitetest.com/mypage.php`, it should work.
UPD. I checked and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the file in the site root folder. It will be accessible.
Example: if your site root is `/var/www/html/` or `public_html` then put the file in html/public_html folder where others WordPress files & folders are like wp-content, wp-includes, wp-admin etc.